# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file; Only when trying to start app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, uglifyjs

So if I want to npm install a package or check the node or npm version it works but if I try to start the app with any of the scripts it shows this. [EDITED]

```
$ npm start

> nibblin@0.0.0 start C:\Users\trevc\Desktop\Projects\nibblin
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nibblin@0.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run 
client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nibblin@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\trevc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08- 
05T14_06_10_006Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package

```
{
  "name": "nibblin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node ./bin/www",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1"
  }
}
```

After deleting all the node modules and trying to reinstall I'm faced with this

```
$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading 
Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading 
Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major 
version bump

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall 
C:\Users\trevc\Desktop\Projects\nibblin\client\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack- 
plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node 
lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\trevc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08- 
05T14_50_21_506Z-debug.log
```

This is only happening in my client folder made with create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm script you are running is `node server.js` but in your package.json you define start script as `node ./bin/www`.

In [react_redux_express_starter](https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_redux_express_starter) boiler player there is no bin or www folder. so i guess either you copied a package.json from another boilerplate or messed up with filed structure or running the command in a wrong directory.